# Translation of "the past shall live" into Latin

Tags: classical-latin, english-to-latin-translation, translation-check

I am translating the motto, "The Past Shall Live" into classical Latin. Currently, I have *Praeteritum Vivet*, which I think makes sense, but I'd appreciate the input of those more skilled than I.

Comment: Did you ever settle on a proper translation? Or something that sounds pretty and means "The Past Shall Live?"

Comment: I think *preteritum vivet* works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More idiomatic, I think, would be *praeterita exsurgent*: "The past (things) will rise up." Singular *praeteritum* sounds like there's one past thing you have in mind, and *exsurgo* seems (to me at least) more natural in Latin than *vivo* of a thing that can't actually be alive.

Comment: This is the correct answer. You could even quote Lewis and Short: "Subst.: prae-tĕrĭta , ōrum, n., things gone by, the **past**."

Comment: Welcome, by the way. And great user name!

Comment: Thanks! Good catch on Lewis and Short.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. _Exsurgant_ has a nice feel in the sense that it feels more "energized" than simply saying it's alive.

Comment: If you want "shall live," use *exsurgent*. *exsurgant* is subjunctive, which would mean "may the past rise up."

Answer (score 2):

"The past shall live" implies that it is currently dead; awaiting, presumably, a resurrection. How about present tense, vivit, as in historia vivit = history lives. The sense, the past segues into the future at a "junction" called the present; therefore, both "live" in the present. Alternatively, there is no present, just a perpetual transition between past/ future.

Comment: I really prefer this; my audience will presumably not speak Latin, so this will be more intuitive to them. I also agree that present tense makes more sense for what I want to convey. Thanks, @tony!